# Show progress of wallpaper android

Tags: java, android, loading, wallpaper

I am creating a wallpaper app and I'm trying to get the current state of it when it's loading and get this information and set it on a progress bar. I know how to get some information about the wallpaper but I don't know how to get the current status.

```
try {
  WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I get this event? I've tried many things but failed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need answers anymore. I found a solution. If someone needs it, here's what I did:

```
try {

                                    if (resource != null){

                                        WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);
                                        Toast.makeText(WallpaperDetailsActivity.this, "Aplicado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        progressBar.hideProgressBar();

                                    }
```

The resource I have add is the bitmap and I used glide to convert it. I hope It helps someone.